# Show number of products added to cart [Woocommerce - Webhook]

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, webhooks, hook-woocommerce, cart

I worked on a new function on my child theme which consists of displaying on the product the number of times it has already been added to the cart.
*Example: if I have 3 tshirts and 1 jeans in my basket, it must respectively appear under the article tshirt > 3 and under the article jeans > 1*

I have already managed to make them appear individually.
Unfortunately, they all appear after AND under all products.

I am trying to retrieve the class "post-id" contained in the

of the article in order to display only the line which also contains the class "post-id".
But that's where I'm stuck.
I can't make the loop correctly.

```
/* Afficher le nb de produit dans le panier */
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'nb_product_cart' );
function nb_product_cart() {
    
    global $post;
    $post_id = $post->ID;

    global $woocommerce;
        
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $item = $cart_item['data'];
        $item_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

        if( $item_id = $item_id ) {

            if(!empty($item) && get_class('product-',$item_id)) { // Faire les modifs de la condition
                $quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];
                echo '<div class=" added post-'. $item_id . '">' . $quantity . '</div>'; //ajouter class nbproduct
            
            }
            else {
                echo '<div class="nbproduct">0</div>';
            }
        
        }
    
    }   
};

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'nb_product_cart' );
```

Can you help me fix my loop error please?

In addition, the figure would also have to update itself thanks to Woocommerce's ajax.
I know that it is necessary to use this option But I do not see how to integrate it in my code.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'ajax_add_to_cart_fragment' );

function ajax_add_to_cart_fragment( $fragments ) {

    $fragments[ '.nbproduct' ] = '???';
    return $fragments;

 }
```

I need your help please.

You will find below the final objective that our code must give.
[End Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ge2xy.png)